# Symbol information not found (Warning VSP2701) while inspecting VS Profiler results

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

we are using c# and visual studio 2013 premium to implement a WPF Windows Application. Right now one of our customers is getting 100% CPU load. There is no specific action which leads to this problem. It is happening on any screen in the application, it comes out from nothing and we have no clue what the problem is. Beside that, the application has very minimal CPU load. But if the problem happens, there is no rescue other than closing (or killing) the application and to restart.

So we send our customer the Perfomance Profiler of Visual Studio (VsPerfCmd.exe) and told him to profile the application after the problem started by attaching to the process which is using 100% CPU.

Now we got the result file and if I try to open that file (PerfToolOutput.vsp) in visual studio, the .Net Framework symbols are loaded, but the assemblies of our application are not.

I got the following warning:
Warning VSP2701: C:\Program Files (x86)\My Company Name\MyAppName\MyApp.exe could not be found when looking for symbol information.

Because I think that visual studio is looking for the PDB files of that compilation the customer is using, I checked out the matching version of the application from subversion, rebuild it, copied the output to the exact folder and set up symbol settings to point to that folder.

But I am still getting this warning and can't view stack trace or method infos of my application. What need I do to be able to load symbols of my application?

Thanks,
Koray

Comment: Every build of the application is unique (the outputs are non-deterministic), so you will need the exact matching PDBs from the customer that match the build of the .exe that was being profiled

Comment: My problem is that we release only the binaries, not the pdb's. So, is my only choice to send my customer a rebuild of that version including the pdb's and let him profile again? Is there a drawback to always release pdb's with any version?